# Non-symmetric polynomials, game

Tags: polynomials, recreational-mathematics, symmetric-polynomials

This is a game I thought was easy but appears to be too hard for me... I'm trying to find a polynomial in x,y,z (they commute) such that permutations of the variables only give rise to 2 different polynomials (the polynomial itself and one other). Can you find one?

Comment: You may add that each of the variables $X,Y,Z$ do appear in the polynomial. Otherwise $X+Y$ is an example.

Comment: Doesn't it give rise to X + Y, X + Z and Y + Z ?? That's 3 polynomials

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. I thought you want to permute only the variables which appear in the polynomial.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, sorry...

Comment: are you sure it's possible? it seems to me that either the polynomial is fully symmetric or it distinguishes one of the variables in which case you get at least three different polynomials

Comment: That's what seemed to me too, but it's supposed to be possible